# Suspend only works once on Toshiba Satellite

Tags: 13.10, laptop, suspend

I've been wanting to use Ubuntu on my laptop along side with windows, and I have tried 12.04 LTE, 13.04, and now currently 13.10 (64-bit).

I'm using a Toshiba Satellite, but I have had an issue everytime. When closing my laptop lid, it will go into suspend mode, like normal, but when resuming, it turns the laptop fan on full power, and will no longer go into suspend mode when closing the lid, unless I reboot.

Basically, everytime I boot up Ubuntu, I get to put it in suspend mode once.

Comment: Did you solve this? Or was it fixed on Ubuntu 14.04 now?

Comment: Which Toshiba Sattelite model are you using?

Answer (score 0):

if I got you right, check the System Settings(can be found on side panel)/Power as by default on my OS it was set to `Don't Suspend` you can choose `Suspend` when inactive for `5/10/30/hour`

Comment: I mean for when I close the laptop lid. it's set to suspend when I close it, but it won't quite work.